# Parabolic cylinder functions - explicit estimates?

Tags: special-functions, na.numerical-analysis, nt.number-theory

I need estimates for the parabolic cylinder functions $U(a,z)$ (first studied by Whittaker).

Most work in the literature focuses on $a$ real. As it happens, I am interested in $U(a,z)$ on a strip in the complex plane:

$|Re(a)|<=1/2$,
$|Re(z)|$ bounded,
$|Im(a)|$ large ($|Im(a)|\geq max(200,10 |Im(z)|)$, say).

What is known then? What can be proven easily by a non-specialist using known techniques?
What I need is a relatively simple estimate for $U(a,z)$ in this range; I do not necessarily need a very good error term (an order-of-magnitude estimate is fine), but I absolutely need all constants in the bound for the error term to be explicit.

(A 1961 paper by Olver gives bounds that are qualitatively strong enough throughout the range, but, unfortunately, the constants are not explicit, and, since the bounds are based on asymptotic series (in Poincaré's sense), making the constants explicit is non-trivial. A 1965 paper, also by Olver, seems useful, but the range in which it works out things in detail is essentially disjoint from the above.)

Comment: Can you give a link that explains the concepts and notations that you use in your post?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask

Comment: Sure: http://dlmf.nist.gov/12

Alternatively, see section 19 of Abramowitz-Stegun, Handbook of Mathematical Functions: http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_685.htm

Comment: Just before anybody says this - yes, I am trying to use the saddle-point method, but finding and using an optimal contour is tricky; I suspect I may to some extent be redoing work that Olver (say) already did. His book has some things on bounds on error terms, but applying them is another matter.


Comment: ... and it is easy to make errors: http://iopscience.iop.org/0022-3700/11/18/002/pdf/jbv11i18pL535.pdf

Comment: Can you state what sort of estimate you need? From above, from below,
or an approximate formula, or what? What does it mean "relatively simple"?

Comment: From above, with explicit error terms. "Relatively simple" - I don't actually need constants for every truncation of a Poincare-style series, say, but just for the truncation after the first- or second-order term.